# Seven bars digits recognition - Computer vision

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, image-recognition, python-tesseract

I am trying to identify the numbers representing the time that are in the left corner at the bottom of the following image.

[image]

Specifically this is the piece of image that I need to recognize:

[image]

The digits are in a seven bars format.

I am using opencv and tesseract, but I am not obtaining good results with any of the filters that I am applying.

This is the code developed (I am assuming that the section where the numbers are, is already identified, so that's my starting point):

```
image = cv2.imread("C:\example2.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 200, 255)

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(edged)
```

Have tried with another set of filters but none of them gives me a result that is near to the image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this [digit recognition post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/13/recognizing-digits-with-opencv-and-python/) by Adrian Rosebrock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tesseract likes black text on white background. Also, it likes [characters to be a minimum height](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/master/FAQ-Old.md#is-there-a-minimum--maximum-text-size-it-wont-read-screen-text).

I passed `cv2.THRESH_OTSU` to do [Otsu thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) and `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV` to invert image (change black to white and white to black). At the original size, the "9" was recognized as "q". I resized by factor of 2, and recognition was better.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

img = cv2.imread('example2.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  

thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
thresh = cv2.resize(thresh, (0,0), fx=2, fy=2)  # scale image 2X

detected_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, config = '--psm 6')
print(detected_text)
```

which gives

```
9:47
```

Comment: Thank you, it passes the correct answer in the case you have pointed. However when I do the same with the other image it passes me S:92 (it is close 5:02). I am not sure it can be useful (if it is possible to set that only is going to find numbers and in a specific range of numbers, since are minutes and seconds).

Comment: You should look at the image after all processing to see how it looks. Either with imshow or saving it with imwrite. You might have to mess with thresholding parameters. Also, you might try scale factor of 3.